# IF ELSE Statement way

Tags: java, if-statement

I made a program to calculate total price based on user's input. It is working fine, but i would like to know how to cut the code but to have the same output.

Especially on IF ELSE statement, I would like to know how not to repeat myself in those blocks. Is there any other way I can write ouputs after IF ELSE blocks, or they have to be individually inside of those blocks? Thanks.
Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;

public class GasCalc
{
   public static void main(String[] args)`enter code here`
   {
      double gasPrice,carGallons,fullTank,totalPrice;


      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Do you want to calculate full tank (y/n) ");
      String askMe=input.next();


      if
      (askMe.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
      {
         DecimalFormat num=new DecimalFormat("$,###.00");
         System.out.print("What is the price of 1 gallon of gas ? ");
         gasPrice=input.nextDouble();
         System.out.print("How many gallons does your vehicle accept ? ");
         fullTank=input.nextDouble();
         totalPrice=gasPrice*fullTank;
         System.out.println("You will pay "+num.format(totalPrice)+" for the full tank of gas");
      }
      else
         if(askMe.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
         {
            DecimalFormat num=new DecimalFormat("$,###.00");
            System.out.print("How many gallons do you need ? ");
            carGallons=input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("What is the price of 1 gallon of gas ? ");
            gasPrice=input.nextDouble();
            totalPrice=gasPrice*carGallons;
            System.out.println("You will pay "+num.format(totalPrice)+" for "+carGallons+" gallons of gas");
         }
   }
```

}

Comment: ok i will try that. Do you know any other way by not creating new methods?

Comment: Personally I would maybe take the DecimalFormat out to just before the if statement. but the rest I would probably leave as is just to keep it readable

Comment: good, decimalformat outside is good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly - you don't want to repeat the same code in the 'if' and the 'else' parts of an `if` statement.

The way you would do this is to the same as anywhere else: extract the common code as a function/method which is called from both places.

Comment: Ok, so basically to make new method and call it in a code.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the last two statements outside, that way your calculation and printing can be done outside the if-else block.
You can rename fullTank and carGallons to gallons, so both variables have the same name, that way the last two statements can be used outside if-else.

```
totalPrice=gasPrice*gallons;
System.out.println("You will pay "+num.format(totalPrice)+" for the full tank of gas");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a method and factorize the local variable num, used in both `if` and `else` :

```
public class GasCalc {

    private static double readDouble(Scanner in, String msg) {
        System.out.print(msg);
        return in.nextDouble();
    }

    private static String readString(Scanner in, String msg) {
        System.out.print(msg);
        return in.next();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double gasPrice, carGallons, fullTank, totalPrice;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String askMe = readString(input,"Do you want to calculate full tank (y/n) ");
        DecimalFormat num = new DecimalFormat("$,###.00");

        if (askMe.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            gasPrice = readDouble(input,"What is the price of 1 gallon of gas ? ");
            fullTank = readDouble(input,"How many gallons does your vehicle accept ? ");
            totalPrice = gasPrice * fullTank;
            System.out.println("You will pay " + num.format(totalPrice) + " for the full tank of gas");
        } else if (askMe.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            carGallons = readDouble(input,"How many gallons do you need ? ");
            gasPrice = readDouble(input,"What is the price of 1 gallon of gas ? ");
            totalPrice = gasPrice * carGallons;
            System.out.println("You will pay " + num.format(totalPrice) + " for " + carGallons + " gallons of gas");
        }
    }
}
```

You could actually factorize even more but it would make little sense to create another method for such a specific treatment. If you are using JDK 8 and understand the lambda expressions, go for it.

Comment: I think your code is very logical, I just have to figure it out since I have never coded that way before. Beginner here :).

Comment: You are repeating the same scheme several times : displaying a message to the user, and then request an input. Thus, it seems to be a good idea to factorize it with the `readDouble` method.

Comment: You are right. Your code seems to be good way to go. Unfortunately, so far that was the only way I learned to code, but now I see the point in creating readDouble method and calling it later in the code. Thank you for explanation. I will definitely have to play with new methods more.

Comment: When i tried to run te program i got this error message displayed

Comment: ----jGRASP exec: javac -g GasCalcInvoking.java

GasCalcInvoking.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
   private static double readDouble(Scanner in, String msg) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class GasCalcInvoking
GasCalcInvoking.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
   private static double readString(Scanner in, String msg) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class GasCalcInvoking
GasCalcInvoking.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
      Scanner       input = new Scanner(System.in);
      ^

Comment: Fixed, there were many minor mistakes. Sorry, I usually at least compile the code I post on SO.

Comment: No problem, thanks for your effort, I don't want to be pain in the.. but java said it cannot find symbol Scanner

Comment: GasCalcInvoking.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
   private static double readDouble(Scanner in, String msg) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class GasCalcInvoking
GasCalcInvoking.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
   private static String readString(Scanner in, String msg) {

Comment: I have just renamed GasCalc to GasCalcInvoke , I hope that did not make any problem

Comment: You should review the basics of Java, no offense. You need to import `Scanner`, I just removed the package and import statements are they don't contribute to the answer

Comment: Right. I added them, since i copied your code into jgrasp, i did not realize they were removed. The code is working. I appreciate your help.